# How to determine if ping reply has reached its timeout?

Tags: c#, timeout, console-application, ping, roundtrip

I need to decide if timeout has occurred and save the entry into list array.

This is how I ping and add the round trip value to one list array:

```
static void Ping()
{
    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + "Start the test? (y/n): ");

    if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y")
    {
        List<int> lag = new List<int>();

        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int server = 1; server <= 139; server++)
        {
            string url = "world" + server.ToString() + ".runescape.com";

            Console.WriteLine("Checking world " + server + "...");

            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = ping.Send(url);

            lag.Add(int.Parse(reply.RoundtripTime.ToString()));
        }

    // ... More Code Here ...

    }
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Status property

```
reply.Status
```

it returns an IPStatus which should have the according status.

Comment: @HelpNeeder Nice! glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use the value in PingReply.Status to determine whether a timeout occurred or not. MSDN documentation states:

> If the value of Status is not Success, you should not use the values
>   returned by the RoundtripTime, Options or Buffer properties. The
>   RoundtripTime and Buffer properties will return zero, and the Options
>   property will return null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.status.aspx